# Checking the result of running process with C#

Tags: c#, process

[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ms_joc/archive/2005/04/08/406608.aspx) has the following code.

```
Process p = new Process();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("/COVERAGE ");
sb.Append(exeFileName);
p.StartInfo.FileName = "vsinstr.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = sb.ToString();
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
// Look at return code – 0 for success
```

The comment says I need to check the return code, but `p.WaitForExit()` doesn't return anything.

- Q1 : What return code do I need to check?
- Q2 : Normally, how one can check if running process is OK or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Q1, check the `Process.ExitCode` property.

For Q2, exit codes for success and failure are defined by the called process itself, but conventionally 0 indicates success and anything else indicates failure.

Answer (score 2):

just look at the [ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx) property to see if the process exited happily or not.

With respect to a running process, you can watch the [standard error stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) to see if any messages are printed there. Chances are they will represent some kind of problem, but this is even more implementation-dependant than the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

After the process completes, the property `ExitCode` of the System.Diagnostics.Process object instance should contain the program status code.

Answer (score 0):

Just check

```
p.ExitCode
```

after process exits.
[Process.ExitCode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exitcode.aspx)